# Intelligent use of labels and newcounter

Tags: macros, counters

In a document I am tracking a list of tasks.  Lets call them A (Task 1), B (Task 2), and C (Task 3).  I'm trying to create a command `\mytask` that will let me add the task based on a label, and other arguments that will be added to the document command as this evolves.

As I add tasks, I want to be able to reference them and determine their status as either `New`, or `Continuing`.  Right now, I'm trying to distinguish between their states with `\@ifundefined{r@#1}` and the labels `Defined` and `Undefined`.

I'm surprised to see, that when I include `\refstepcounter{task}\label{#1}%` in the command, that I get really weird numbering, and the `iflabelexists` logic doesn't seem to be sensitive to the placement of the `\label` command.

My output is:

> 1 Tests
>
> 1.1 Defined A task 4
>
> 1.2 Defined B task 3
>
> 1.3 Defined B task 3
>
> 1.4 Defined A task 4
>
> 1.5 Defined C task 5

While I somewhat expected the numbers to be a little staggered because IO but the `\refstepcounter` after the titles that show what the task number is, I wasn't expecting the A to be a larger number than the B.  Additionally, I expcet the Status (Defined or undefined) to be:

> 1 Tests
>
> 1.1 Undefined A
>
> 1.2 Undefined B
>
> 1.3 Defined B
>
> 1.4 Defined A
>
> 1.5 Defined C

I can't explain the why any use of `refstepcounter` toggles the ifundefined flag, but I'm guessing that logic of

```
if Exists(A) == false
   Show title demonstrating the proof that the label hasn't been created yet
   create label and counter
   % NOTE:  this logic is proof of concept only, real situation, this can not be worked around by starting from a lower counter number
else
   % label already exists
   Show title demonstrating the proof that the label has been created yet
   Don't increase counter
```

failing has something to do with the multiple runs of the compiler that Tex needs...  Originally I thought my TOC was toggling the first use of the labels, but I think I've got a bigger problem.

Is there a dynamic way to work with custom counters like this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\iflabelexists}[3]{\@ifundefined{r@#1}{#3}{#2}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{task}
\renewcommand{\thetask}{\arabic{task}}
\crefname{task}{task}{task}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mytask}{ m }
{
    %   #1 - Task label

    \iflabelexists{#1}%
    {%
        \subsection{Defined $#1$ \cref{#1}}%
    }{%
        \subsection{Undefined $#1$ \cref{#1}}%
        \refstepcounter{task}\label{#1}%
    }%  
}

\begin{document}

    \section{Tests}

    \setcounter{task}{0}% Start value

    \mytask{A}

    \mytask{B}

    \mytask{B}

    \mytask{A}

    \mytask{C}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The test whether `\r@<label>` exists is reliable only for labels defined in the previous LaTeX run, not in the current one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{test}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{r@test}{undefined}{defined}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

At the first LaTeX run it will print “undefined”, at the next run it will print “defined”.

When `\label{test}` is processed, LaTeX writes `\newlabel{test}{{1}{1}}` in the `.aux` file, but it *doesn't* define `\r@test`. It is `\newlabel{test}{{1}{1}}` that does, so the test

```
\@ifundefined{r@#1}
```

you're using will not do what you aim for.

You have to define your own macro for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\iflabelexists}[3]{\@ifundefined{engbirdr@#1}{#3}{#2}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{task}
\renewcommand{\thetask}{\arabic{task}}
\crefname{task}{task}{task}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\mytask}{ m }
{
    %   #1 - Task label
    \iflabelexists{#1}%
    {%
        \subsection{Defined $#1$ \cref{#1}}%
    }{%
        \subsection{Undefined $#1$ \cref{#1}}%
        \global\expandafter\let\csname engbirdr@#1\endcsname\@empty
        \refstepcounter{task}\label{#1}%
    }%  
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \section{Tests}

    \setcounter{task}{0}% Start value

    \mytask{A}

    \mytask{B}

    \mytask{B}

    \mytask{A}

    \mytask{C}

\end{document}
```

[image]